# Accessing each column of each row on SqlCommand and ExecuteReader

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, select

Is there a way to index the reader variable so I can access every single user that's being selected? As this only gets the first record everytime

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from users", con))
{
    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                user = new Users(reader["name"].ToString(), reader["image_path"].ToString());

                //MessageBox.Show(reader[1].ToString() + " " + reader[2].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the reader is only one (don't get the reader[1]), but each while iteration will return a new row.. I don't understand exactly what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're misinterpreting the purpose of SqlDataReader.

Each loop through

```
while (reader.Read())
```

will iterate through a row of the returned dataset. If you wish to show each user in a message box, your code ought to look something like the following.

```
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from users", con))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                user = new Users(reader["name"].ToString(), reader["image_path"].ToString());
                MessageBox.Show(user.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

If you wanted to show all the users joined together at the end, you'd want to do something like the following.

```
    var users = new List<Users>();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from users", con))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                user = new Users(reader["name"].ToString(), reader["image_path"].ToString());
                users.Add(user);
            }
        }
    }

    MessageBox.Show(string.Join(" ", users.Select(x => x.ToString()));
```